# mongodb keyfile and -auth

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replicaset

I'm trying to learn mongoDB Replica set. Now I have three servers: one to be primary, one to be secondary, and the last one to be the arbiter. I was told to build a keyfile and use it for mongod startup command. So, what does this keyfile really do? I do not understand the role a keyfile is playing. And, when I use this keyfile, does it automatically turn -auth on? Do I have to create a new user and auth him? If I have to do this operation, on which machine should I take this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key file contains the key, or password if you like, that the cluster members use to communicate.

The key file should reside on all cluster members.

Specifying a key file should imply authorization enabled.

If I'm not mistaken, you should create the user on the primary, this will apply to all three servers.